# Why is this Meteor example app only showing a blank page?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to get this Meteor app to work: https://github.com/jpsarda/meteor-pen

I followed the instructions exactly, installed meteor, cloned the git repository, cd into the cloned directory and then typed meteor. It says

```
'Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/'
```

but when I go to the webpage is just shows a completely blank page.

I also deployed it to Meteors servers to test and it still just shows a blank page. Why?

http://another-out-of-control-leaderboard-adventure.meteor.com <-- Just shows blank page??

Comment: Open console on website, it has bugs. Specifically it is calling 'add' on undefined. Debug your code locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have meteorite installed on your machine because it uses the router package

install meteorite (http://oortcloud.github.io/meteorite/) and then run mrt update inside your app folder and then run meteor and it will work

Comment: then, when you run meteor, use $mrt instead of $meteor